# AlphaFold: How do they determine the 100% accuracy threshold?

Tags: protein-folding, artificial-neural-network

From what I read, it seems the current situation is like this: latest cutting-edge lab techniques get to an accuracy of around 90%. For example, they put a protein under an electron microscope or something, and from the images obtained they achieve a precision of 90%. Now Deepmind features an AI that has demonstrated in contests that it can also virtually fold proteins to 90% accuracy. Therefore, the problem is kind of solved.

Please correct me if my interpretation is wrong. But if it's correct, then a big question remains: how the hell can they know if a configuration is 100% true? Even the best technology can only reach 90%, so where do they get that 100% for comparison?

Comment: Just a guess - they could have created a synthetic protein where they know the exact sequence and used it as a reference?

Comment: Can you tell a bit more on the source which claims 90% precision of the laboratory methods of structural determination?

Comment: It seems I've made a mistake there. Lab results were actually set out as the 100 threshold, and Alphafold was compared against it. Because even lab techniques can have errors, they consider 90+ scores are about as good as 100.